# Formal Methods (Z-notation) - adding a new multiple relation

Tags: formal-languages, formal-methods, z-notation

We 've got an operation Bus_Arrives that accepts the following

A LINE, a BUS_ID and a BUSROAD

- A bus of a given line arrives at the station and is assigned an empty
  bus-road, if one is  available. Otherwise it enters a queue.

--------New_Bus_Arrives-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Δ Bus_Station

| busline?: LINE

| bus?: BUS_ID

| br?: BUSROAD

==============================================

| preconditions go here(the case of adding that to the queue is implemented, but I am not adding it since its not related with the question.) below is how the system changes after this operation get completed.

| free' = free \ {br?}

| routing' = routing

| departure' = departure U {br? |--> bus?}

| **visits' = visits U {br? |--> routing(|line?|) }**

---

***My question is: if the visits is represented correctly is Z, for example, when the routing(line?) relation is called it returns a set of station elements {station1,station2,station3}. However, when I am mapping this to the visits relation to update it I am doing this: br? maps to {station1,station2,station3}. Is this possible or i have to say that br? maps to every single element of the set separately. Also if this is the case how is it represented in Z?***

> Extra information about what is described:

routing: For  every  correspondence  bus-line,  what  are  the  stations  the  bus  passes  through to arrive there(i.e - Line 8 travels to L.A, N.Y and Miami).

routing: LINE <--> STATION (relation)

---

free: Which bus-roads are available.

free: Π BUSROAD (power-set)

---

departure: For every bus what bus-line it departs from (example from A departs bus AY123).

departure: LINE --> BUS_ID (function)

---

visits: For every bus-road that currently has a bus assigned, what stations it will visit. A bus-road can either have one and only one bus on it or be available.

visits: BUS_ROAD <--> STATION (relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem.

The current operation is not correct, since after making my specification in CZT I verified it and I get the following message:

> Expected type: ℙ ( PLATFORM × STATION ) × ℙ ( PLATFORM × STATION )
>   Actual type: ℙ ( PLATFORM × STATION ) × ℙ ( PLATFORM × ℙ STATION )

Which means that each element should be mapped seperately.

**The actual symbol that should be used is the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).**

In Zet is represented as `visits′ = visits ⊕ {br?} X route(|line?|)`

Which will return all the mappings as (br?,station) which is equivalent to br? |--> station, therefore it can be used.

Note: cartesian product can be applied between sets, thus br? should be treated as a set.